# Measuring distance in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I was trying to measure a distance between a bunch of points and a polyline in QGIS and some people suggest me to use NNJoin Plugin. It worked smoothly but I crosschecked the results with  some manual measurement and in average the results are about 20 km off. Is there another way to do this with a more precise results?

edit: I try to measure the distance between volcanoes to its related subduction zone. I use WGS 84 Geographic coordinate system in my layers. I didnt do much with the NNJoin because there are only inputs for the two vector layer and for the output layer. The measurement that I used as reference is the measurement with measurement line tool.
[image: comparassion between the two measurement]

actually I dont know for sure the unit of the NNJoin measurement results but I just asume its in hundreds kilos..

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Could you please edit your question to include the coordinate system you are using in addition to the steps you tool to create the measurements?

Comment: i think the units is in degrees - 2.5 would be around 275km at the equator, less as you get further way from the equator. If that's Sumatra you're close to the equator, and it seems to match what the measure tool is showing

Comment: I guess you are right. I multiply all the results with 111.325 and get better results, still got a few kilos error on the point at the high latitude, but a lot better. Thanks.

Comment: The NNJoin documentation (available through the Help-button or http://arken.nmbu.no/~havatv/gis/qgisplugins/NNJoin/) says that "The join and distance calculations is performed using the join layer CRS" and "Joining layers with an unprojected CRS is allowed, but the distance calculations are then done using decimal degreees, and the distances returned will be in decimal degrees"